# Need to find & replace text in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, find

I have a very long query with several date variables that are set to pull dynamic date ranges (prior month, prior day, etc.).

This works well on a forward moving basis but I need to do a one-time historical backfill of the reporting, which means I'm going to needs to run the query for 20-40 previous time periods.

It's a very long query but it utilizes about 3 dynamic date variables over and over. I'm trying to find a way to find & replace something like

`DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getdate()) - 2, 0)`

With

`'2019-02-01 00:00:00'`

but I can't seem to do that in SSMS.

I've tried copying and pasting to word, excel, etc. but I'm running into a problem with my straight line quotes being converted to "smart quotes". I've turned the auto-formatting settings off that affect this but am still having the issue.

Is there a better way to do this? Or something I'm missing?

I know that blanket "find & replace" operations are generally not a good idea but due to the structure/permissions of the DB and query this is really the best/quickest solution.

Comment: Post your complete update statement and some of the sample data and I can help you

Comment: You can use Notepad++, just paste the query inside it, and change the language to SQL, then use find & replace, it's very useful and I've been using it for a long time with no issues.

Comment: That works perfectly, exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getdate()) - 3, 0), 
 120)
```

check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/41922

Comment: oopsy that would be -3 rather than -2

Comment: Is that going to modify everything in the query window? the problem is that I have a query which is a long list of stored procedure executions, temptable creations, loops, etc.

Comment: I literally need to find and replace the string like you would in word so that I can re-run the 15K+ line query.

Comment: @sccrbrg post it what you have